# java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized with YouTubeThumbnailView

Tags: android, youtube-api, illegalstateexception, android-youtube-api

I am using youtube api in my android app to load thumbnails for videos in my `RecyclerView`. Following is my implementation in side my adapter:

```
private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
```

This holds the loaders for the `YouTubeThumbnailView` for each adapter element. This is the code we use for initialisation of the `YouTubeThumbnailLoader`(s):

```
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(holder.thumbnail);
                final String videoId = Utils.getYoutubeIdFromUrl(m.getYoutubeUrl());
                holder.thumbnail.setTag(videoId);
                if(loader != null) {
                     loader.setVideo(videoId);
                    }
                }
```

When initialising the elements of the `ViewHolder`, I initialise the thumbnail loaders as follows:

```
private void setupYoutubeThumbnail() {
            thumbnail.initialize(RiyazApplication.applicationInstance
                            .getString(R.string.youtube_api_developer_key),
                    thumbnailListener);
            thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(v.getTag() != null && itemClickListener != null) {
                        itemClickListener.onClickVideo(mList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                    }
                }
            });
```

and the code for releasing the thumbnail loaders is as follows:

```
public void releaseThumbnailLoaders() {
        final Set<YouTubeThumbnailView> keysSet = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.keySet();
        for(YouTubeThumbnailView view: keysSet) {
            final YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(view);
            if(loader != null) {
                loader.release();
            }
        }
        thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.clear();
    }
```

In my crashalytics, I am getting the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: YouTubeServiceEntity not initialized
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1497)
       at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1443)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.l$a$a.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.o.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.p.(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.ac.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView$a.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.g(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$c.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$b.a(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5052)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

I am not sure, why am I getting this. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hi, what does the YouTube player has to do with loading videos thumbnails? the two things should be separated.

Comment: @Pierfran have a look at the 8th one of the stacktrace. There is thumbnail view mentioned in the stacktrace.

Comment: Why not downloading thumbnails using the YouTube Data APIs and display them in an imageview?

Comment: Well.. I haven't tried that but this should also have no problem right ?

Comment: where is the code for `YouTubeServiceEntity`

Comment: Also, if you don't want you developer key taken, don't put it in a string. Anyone can look at them by decompling the apk.

Comment: @Swapnil Did you find any solution to the above crashes? My crashlytics is filled with these crashes. And I am not able to re-create them.

Answer (score 1):

Put your initaizle statement in a try-catch statement like so:

```
try {   
 
  thumbnail.initialize(RiyazApplication.applicationInstance.getString(R.string.youtube_api_developer_key), thumbnailListener);
} 
catch(IllegalStateException w){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code. I am using a static video list to populate in RecyclerView. Below code has been implemented using RecyclerView in activity.

Activity:-

```
public class YouTubeVideoListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerViewList;
private RecyclerAdapter adapter;

private static final List<VideoEntry> VIDEO_LIST;
static {
    List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
    list.add(new VideoEntry("YouTube Collection", "Y_UmWdcTrrc"));
    list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Tap", "1KhZKNZO8mQ"));
    list.add(new VideoEntry("Chrome Multitask", "UiLSiqyDf4Y"));
    list.add(new VideoEntry("Google Fiber", "re0VRK6ouwI"));
    list.add(new VideoEntry("Autocompleter", "blB_X38YSxQ"));
    list.add(new VideoEntry("GMail Motion", "Bu927_ul_X0"));
    list.add(new VideoEntry("Translate for Animals", "3I24bSteJpw"));
    VIDEO_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_you_tube_video_list);

    recyclerViewList=findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);

    adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, VIDEO_LIST);

    recyclerViewList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerViewList.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    adapter.releaseLoaders();
}

}
```

Model class:-

```
public class VideoEntry {
private final String text;
private final String videoId;

public VideoEntry(String text, String videoId) {
    this.text = text;
    this.videoId = videoId;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public String getVideoId() {
    return videoId;
}
}
```

Recycler Adapter:-

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private final List<VideoEntry> entries;
private final List<View> entryViews;
private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private final ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;

private boolean labelsVisible;
private Context context;

public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<VideoEntry> entries) {
    this.entries = entries;
    this.context = context;

    entryViews = new ArrayList<>();
    thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<>();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();

    labelsVisible = true;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.you_tube_row, parent, false);
    return new Holder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Holder h = (Holder) holder;
    VideoEntry entry = entries.get(position);

    YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(h.thumbnail);
    if (loader == null) {
        // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
        //    current videoId in the tag.
        h.thumbnail.setTag(entry.getVideoId());
    } else {
        // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
        //    on the loader.
        h.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
        loader.setVideo(entry.getVideoId());
    }

    h.label.setText(entry.getText());
    h.label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return entries.size();
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
public void releaseLoaders() {
    for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
        loader.release();
    }
}
public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
    labelsVisible = visible;
    for (View view : entryViews) {
        view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView label;
    YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail;


    Holder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        label = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbnail.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, thumbnailListener);

    }
}

private final class ThumbnailListener implements
        YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
        YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(
            YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
        loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
        thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.put(view, loader);
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_thumbnail);
        String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
        loader.setVideo(videoId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(
            YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
        view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
    }
}
}
```

Recycler list row layout (you_tube_row.xml):-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/no_thumbnail"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

If you want more detail you can download sample code from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/).

Comment: I used the similar sample from the google and wrote the code. If you read my code... it is same to what you have mentioned here. I don't see any difference... Can you please point out something that you noticed?

Comment: Are you having RecyclerView in Fragment?

Comment: Yes .. I use it inside a fragment

Comment: Make Sure you are releasing loaders in onDestroyView method of fragment.

Comment: Is that the problem ?

Comment: May be, I am not sure about it.

Comment: Inside onCreateView(), I am storing reference to the view if already created earlier and not re-initialising it. Also, the adapter is initialised inside onCreate() of the fragment so I am not sure if this is a good idea...

Comment: Try initialising view every time without storing reference to view and release loader in onDestroyView:- @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        adapter.releaseLoaders();
    }

Comment: Tried this... but still facing the same issue!!

Comment: Did u find any fix?